# Javascript - html: How to move an image within a cropped container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, move, crop

I have a drag & drop container on my site that when an image that is too tall for the container is added, it crops the image.

```
   async function add_photo(drag_area) {
  console.log(drag_area + "_file_picker");
  //selecting all required elements
  const dropArea = document.getElementById(drag_area),
    dragText = dropArea.querySelector("header"),
    button = dropArea,
    input = dropArea.querySelector("input");
  let file; //this is a global variable and we'll use it inside multiple functions
  button.onclick = () => {
    input.click(); //if user click on the button then the input also clicked
  }
  input.addEventListener("change", function () {
    //getting user select file and [0] this means if user select multiple files then we'll select only the first one
    file = this.files[0];
    dropArea.classList.add("active");
    showFile(); //calling function
  });
  //If user Drag File Over DropArea
  dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); //preventing from default behaviour
    dropArea.classList.add("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Release to Upload File";
  });
  //If user leave dragged File from DropArea
  dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", () => {
    dropArea.classList.remove("active");
    dragText.textContent = "Drag & Drop to Upload File";
  });
  //If user drop File on DropArea
  dropArea.addEventListener("drop", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); //preventing from default behaviour
    //getting user select file and [0] this means if user select multiple files then we'll select only the first one
    file = event.dataTransfer.files[0];
    showFile(); //calling function
  });
  function showFile() {
    let fileType = file.type; //getting selected file type
    let validExtensions = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"]; //adding some valid image extensions in array
    console.log(file);
    if (validExtensions.includes(fileType)) { //if user selected file is an image file
      let fileReader = new FileReader(); //creating new FileReader object
      fileReader.onload = () => {
        let fileURL = fileReader.result; //passing user file source in fileURL variable
       let imgTag = `<img id="meter_img" style="width:600px;margin:auto;max-height:600px;object-fit: cover;" src="${fileURL}" alt="image">`; //creating an img tag and passing user selected file source inside src attribute
        dropArea.innerHTML = imgTag; //adding that created img tag inside dropArea container
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } else {
      alert("This is not an Image File!");
      dropArea.classList.remove("active");
      dragText.textContent = "Drag & Drop to Upload File";
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to enable users to move the cropped image within the container to make sure the piece(s) of the image they want are visible. How would I accomplish this and still maintain the functionality of the drag & drop & input?

Answer (score 1):

Why won't you just use `object-fit: contain` in CSS on your image element?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI to move the image and get the x, y position offset

```js
$('#draggable').draggable( {
  cursor: 'move',
  containment: 'parent',
  stop: handleDragStop
});

function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {
  var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
  var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.offset.top );
  alert( "Drag stopped!nnOffset: (" + offsetXPos + ", " + offsetYPos + ")n");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" style="width:500px;height:300px;border:1px solid black">
  <div id="draggable" style="width:150px; height:100px;background-color:orange">IMG</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You really don't need jQuery for that.